# SQL - Get rows with one result and selected option - Relation Table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table that has the relations of products and colors. Each product has one or multiple colors. Is it possible to do a query that returns only the products that have one color only and the color wanted  ?

Value from the api : color_slug = white ;

Sample table :

```
color_table
+----------+------------+
| color_id | color_slug |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | white      |
|        2 | blue       |
|        3 | black      |
|        4 | green      |
|        5 | red        |
|        6 | yellow     |
+----------+------------+
```

```
product_table
+------------+--------------+
| product_id | product_name |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | shoes        |
|          2 | shorts       |
|          3 | t-shirt      |
|          4 | jacket       |
|          5 | watch        |
|          6 | glasses      |
+------------+--------------+
```

```
pc_relation
+----+------------+----------+
| id | product_id | color_id |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 |          1 |        5 |
|  2 |          1 |        1 |
|  3 |          2 |        1 |
|  4 |          2 |        4 |
|  5 |          2 |        3 |
|  6 |          3 |        2 |
|  7 |          4 |        1 |
|  8 |          5 |        5 |
|  9 |          5 |        6 |
| 10 |          6 |        1 |
+----+------------+----------+
```

Select unique color values (if i put WHERE color_id = 1 the product colors are not longer of one color only) :

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM pc_relation
// WHERE color_id = 1
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING MIN(color_id) = MAX(color_id)
```

`pc_relation.id = 6,7,10`

```
SELECT *
FROM color_table
INNER JOIN pc_relation ON pc_relation.color_id = color_table.color_id 
INNER JOIN product_table ON pc_relation.product_id  = product_table.product_id
WHERE colors.color_slug = 'white'
```

Values wanted (color_slug = white):

`pc_relation.id = 7,10`
`product_table.product_name  = jacket, glasses`

*all the combinations are unique and indexed. For example I cannot have one product with the same color
twice.

Comment: is it mysql, or postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with your first query.  Move the color comparison to the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM pc_relation
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING MIN(color_id) = MAX(color_id) AND
       MIN(color_id) = 1;
```

You can also phrase this using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select r.*
from pc_relation r
where r.color_id = 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from pc_relation r2
                  where r2.product_id = r.product_id and r2.color_id <> r.color_id
                 );
```

However, the `GROUP BY` method is more general.

Comment: Already did that, but without the MIN on MIN(color_id) = 1; I ll try that now.

Comment: Why the MIN makes the difference ? It worked : MIN(color_table.color_slug) = 'white'

Comment: @bmpf_pt . . . I don't really understand the question.  You need an aggregation function in the `having` clause.